# Why am I unable to use RXJS Observable method in AngularFire2 FirebaseObjectObservable objects?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire

For example the do(fn) function is available for RXJS Observable. But is unavailable when I try to use it on FirebaseListObservable and FirebaseObjectObservable. The error I get is:

```
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'do' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.'
at: '58,8'
source: 'ts'
```

Using the standard latest AngularFirebase library and running it within an Angular 4 / Ionic 3 environment...

Comment: Have you tried importing do operator from Rxjs?
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';`
For more https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/186

Comment: Hey yes, that worked. Was following a tutorial that was using an older version of rxjs where the operators didn't have to be manually imported one by one like they do in the new version. Thank you!